# Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `onClick` was not specified in `AutoFillList`. Check the render method of `App`

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to send Dispatch and State to Props of my presentational component in my Redux application but I keep getting the error stated in the title.

My presentational component looks like this:
**./components/AutoFillList.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const AutoFillList = ({ songTitle, songLink, onClick  }) => (

    <a href={songLink}>
    <li onClick={onClick}>{songTitle}</li>
    </a>
)

AutoFillList.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    songTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    songLink: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default AutoFillList
```

And my Container component looks like this: **./containers/AutoFillLogic.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AutoFillList from '../components/AutoFillList'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        songTitle: state.songTitle,
        songLink: state.songLink
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        onClick: () => {return}
    }
}

const AutoFillLogic= connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AutoFillList)
export default AutoFillLogic
```

**Solution:** Render your smart component instead of your dumb component in App.js as suggested by Florent. So in this case it would mean rendering "AutoFillLogic" instead of "AutoFillList"

Comment: Are yoy sure you're rendering `AutoFillLogic` instead of `AutoFillList`?

Comment: Thank you so much Florent, I was actually rendering AutoFillList. I switched to rendering my smart component and now it works!